# Unable to inject SVG icon to page using Content Script

Tags: javascript, svg, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an chrome extension and I already prepared an content script which should insert some code to page. Among the code is an URL for a SVG file (svg-sprite with some icons) generated using `chrome.runtime.getURL` method:

```
let icon_url = chrome.runtime.getURL('/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account');
```

The HTML is:

```
<svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_small">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="icon_url" />
</svg>
```

After the page is rendered and the code is appended to the existing page, I get kind of the messages in console:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL chrome-extension://lcnpenkakheclpiepbgeaohabcfbjpah/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account from frame with URL https://django545-ed.my.salesforce.com/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?setupid=ForceCom#void. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

This kind of message only appears when I trying to get a specific icon from sprite by symbol (URL ends with `#account`).

I already searched among many sites and I didn't found anything helpful. I learned from the error message that this can be linked with Content Security Policy (CSP) but anything go forward. I also added this resource into manifest to `web_accessible_resources` key, but nothing helped.

I would be grateful for any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: The error message says you can't reference SVGs from a different URL origin. I think you'll have to add the contents of symbols.svg into the web page. Alternatively try setting the icons via CSS background-image which might be able to load directly from icon_url.

Comment: I can't use background-image: some CSS classes modifies the icon fill color and it doesn't work properly. These icons are from the Lightning Design System (SLDS). Currently I use the single icons and it works for some by using `<image>` instead `<use>` but then again it doesn't work with colors (all icons are white on different background colors) - that's why I need the access to icons from sprite SVG.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this at Zenhub (we build a browser extension). I think it has to do with this statement on the docs for the `<use>` element ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)):

> For security reasons, browsers may apply the same-origin policy on use elements and may refuse to load a cross-origin URL in the href attribute. There is currently no defined way to set a cross-origin policy for use elements.

So if you use `<use href="https://some-external-site/file.svg#test">` to load your asset within the context of the extension, it will get blocked. Even if your `href` URL is pointing to local extension asset like: `<use href="chrome-extension://file.svg#test">` you'll get an error like this:

> `Unsafe attempt to load URL <URL> from frame with URL <URL>. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Personally I feel like this is a bug in the browser itself, but it seems like both Chrome and Firefox have this behaviour, so there may be some deeper security reason behind it.

To work around it, we've gone with the approach of injecting the SVG asset directly into the DOM like this ([source](https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/)):

```js
  const svgUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('/file.svg' /* Local path to your SVG here */);
  fetch(svgUrl)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((content) => {
      const template = document.createElement('template');
      template.innerHTML = content;

      const svgElement = Array.from(template.content.childNodes).find(
        (node) => node.nodeName === 'svg',
      );
      if (svgElement) document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
    });
}
```

After that you can load your SVG assets via:

```html
<svg>
   <use href="#icon_url" />
</svg>
```

Note that this means the IDs in your SVG should be globally unique to avoid any conflicts with others on the page, so it's important to prefix them.